# How to use retrofit with response format varies according to a parameter?

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization, retrofit2

I have a login api where response format varies according to type of user logging in.

Json structure with "type" = 4

```
{
    "type": 4,
    "user": {
        "coord_id": 5,
        "coord_login_id": 4,
        "coord_name": "Randall Pfannerstill",
    }
}
```

Json Format with "type" = 2

```
{
    "type": 2,
    "user": {
        "stud_id": 1,
        "stud_reference_id": "3",
    }
}
```

im using this model class for handling "type" 2

```
public class LoginResponse {
    @SerializedName("type")
    public int type;
    @SerializedName("user")
    public User user;

    public class User {
        @SerializedName("stud_id")
        public int stud_id;
        @SerializedName("stud_reference_id")
        public String stud_reference_id;

    }
```

How can handle the case with "type" = 4 with same class (or How should i write a different model class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your JSONs have different key names, I suggest you to use the `Map` instead:

```
public class YourPojo {
    private int type;
    private Map<String, String> user;
}
```

Base on your `type`, you should know which `User` you got from response

Comment: Oh, so i have to use only one map object for any number of strings in the response, right?

Comment: Yes, the `Map` could match any number of key-value pairs in response

Comment: what to do if theres nested objects

Comment: like if there are <String, Object> ,<String Array>, <String, List<Object>> etc . if i store all these values as <String, String> how can i deserialize them?

Comment: Then replace `Map<String, String>` by `Map<String, Object>`. This requires you to know which fields have which type of data. Nested Object will be translated to a Map. Then you can cast it

Comment: But I think it's a design error to have two completely different JSON returned from one API endpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171822/discussion-between-aflah-ali-and-mnh-quyt-nguyn).

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try this

```
public class LoginResponse {
@SerializedName("type")
public int type;
@SerializedName("user")
public User user;

public class User {
    @SerializedName("stud_id")
    public int stud_id;
    @SerializedName("stud_reference_id")
    public String stud_reference_id;


    @SerializedName("coord_id");
    public int coord_id;
    @SerializedName("coord_login_id");
    public int coord_login_id;
    @SerializedName("coord_name")
    public String coord_name;

}
}
```

if data found that is store in variable ...otherwise that field store null data....you need to always check that data is null or not 
means if stud_id found that is store...and coord_id is null...else if crood_id is found that time stud_id is null

Comment: I have just shared a simplified form of my response. Actual response is very long.

Comment: you have three ways...1) every variable change like my example...2) tell your problem with your php developer to change that flow....3) if you need just string is user is "coord" or "stud" tell your php developer to add that only one fiedt that you check is coord or is stud...(not change all class...just add variable for coord or stud taht you can identify)

Comment: This is how my actual response looks like

Comment: `
   {
    "type": 2,
    "user": {
        "stud_id": 1,
        "stud_name": "Robert",
        "school": {
            "school_id": 1,
            "school_name": "ABC School",
            "coordinator": {
                "coord_id": 1,
                "coord_name": "Hulda Crist"
            }
        },
        "item": [
            {
                "item_type": "1",
                "item_name": "Cricket"
            },
            {
                "item_type": "2",
                "item_name": "Judo"
            }
        ]
    }
}
  `

Comment: i will have to, if there isn't a better solution

Comment: you can manually parse it...but is is not proper in your condition....so...dont waste time...just tell your php developer to solve this issue

Comment: The app is having entirely different UI for differnt user types. So the response structure should have to be different.

Comment: "coord_id": 5, and  "stud_id": 1, is both from diffrent url respomse ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171823/discussion-between-aflah-ali-and-birju).